# Npm installing Karma-jasmine doesn't work

Tags: npm, jasmine, karma-runner

I just follow the instructions in there:
http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/intro/installation.html

Karma has been installed correctly.
Though, I can't install karma-jasmine and karma-chrome-launcher. I am actually having a lot's of warnings about README:

```
npm WARN package.json abbrev@1.0.4 No README data
npm WARN package.json ansi@0.2.1 No README data
npm WARN package.json archy@0.0.2 No README data
npm WARN package.json asn1@0.1.11 No README data
```

...

and then a few unmet dependancies:

*

```
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/lib/node_modules/block-stream requires inherits@'~2.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/lib/node_modules/fstream requires inherits@'~2.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/lib/node_modules/fstream-ignore requires inherits@'2' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/lib/node_modules/fstream-npm requires inherits@'2' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/lib/node_modules/glob requires inherits@'2' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/lib/node_modules/npmconf requires inherits@'~2.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/lib/node_modules/tar requires inherits@'2' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
```

*

Any idea where could that come from ?

Comment: Not sure, but this looks like a firewall problem. Are you behind a firewall? Can npm install anything?

Comment: Try this link for instructions to install karma http://samyakwebdev.blogspot.in/

Answer (score -1):

```
Follow below steps to setup karma-jasmine environment

 •  Install nodejs
    o   Download nodejs suitable setup file from https://nodejs.org/download/ website.
    o   Install nodejs using setup file 
    •   Installation of Karma and plugins using npm(node package manager)
    o   Open command prompt
    o   Traverse to project structure
       cd ‘\path of project folder’
       (path till  folder which is having /src folder in it)
    o   Install Karma
       npm install karma --save-dev
    •   New folder in project structure will get created named as ‘node_modules’
    •   If any warnings appear on command prompt ignore them

    o   Install browser plugins(optional)
       npm install karma-jasmine karma-chrome-launcher --save-dev
    •   If any warnings appear on command prompt ignore them
    o   Install Karma command line interpreter globally
       npm install -g karma-cli
    •   If any warnings appear on command prompt ignore them
```